# Content-Disposition Regex pattern not working

Tags: php, regex

I have this string (for example)

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Eminem - Not Afraid1.3gp"
```

and use this pattern on `preg_match()`

```
([^.]+)\:\s([^.]+)
```

What I want is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Eminem - Not Afraid1.3gp"
    [1] => Content-Disposition
    [2] => attachment; filename="Eminem - Not Afraid1.3gp"
)
```

But I get

```
Array
(
    [0] => Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Eminem - Not Afraid1
    [1] => Content-Disposition
    [2] => attachment; filename="Eminem - Not Afraid1
)
```

What is wrong with this pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with the second `([^.]+)`. It stops capturing after seeing the `.` in the filename. So use `(.+)` instead of `([^.]+)` in-order to capture all the remaining characters,

```
([^:]+):\s(.+)
```

[DEMO](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/7wk)

I think it's better to use anchors.

```
^([^:]+):\s(.+)$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                        the beginning of the string
(                        group and capture to \1:
  [^:]+                    any character except: ':' (1 or more
                           times)
)                        end of \1
:                        ':'
\s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
(                        group and capture to \2:
  .+                       any character except \n (1 or more
                           times)
)                        end of \2
$                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                         string
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I would change your first negated character class from a dot to a colon.  The colon does not need to be escaped outside of a class either, it is not a character of special meaning. And then you could match the dot `.` and everything after until the end of the string. I would recommend anchoring your regular expression as well ...

```
^([^:]+):\s([^.]+\..+)$
```

Or simply match the rest of the string inside of the second capturing group ...

```
^([^:]+):\s(.+)$
```

[<kbd>Code Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/207538)